# Can I apply a theme to a specific slide in reveal.js?

Tags: reveal.js

I am using [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) for a presentation. I am using the `white` theme:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reveal.js/css/theme/white.css" id="theme">
```

However, the last slide should have theme `black`.

Can I achieve this? How?

Answer (score 2):

A good way to do this might be to add a marker on your last slide like this:

```html
<section data-state="darkside">
```

In the initialization section of the slideshow put something like this:

```js
Reveal.addEventListener( 'darkside', function() {
    document.getElementById('theme').setAttribute('href','css/theme/night.css'); 
}, false );
```

This way the theme is changed when you reach the given slide. I think you should also consider marking all other slides and change the theme back.